# Call functions that operate on the structures

Tags: c++, function, structure

Two structures and two functions to get info from the user and store it in the functions and then two functions to display the info as well as the main where I call the other functions

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

the structures contain a bunch of categories that don't really matter much I also initialized two structures named Tech1 and Fash1

```
struct Tech {
    int productcode, price, storage;
    string brand, model;
    char screensize;
}Tech1;

struct Fashion {
    int productcode, price;
    string brand, model, gender;
    char size;


}Fash1;
```

these are the functions that get the info from the user and I used cin >> then the struct name followed by a dot then the variable name to store the info into that variable
but when I run the program and pick from main the switch case to call this function it doesn't work, it doesn't even print the cout simple text.

```
void getTechFeaturs() {
    cout << "Enter Product Code: " << endl;
    cin >> Tech1.productcode;
    cout << "Enter Brand name: " << endl;
    cin >> Tech1.brand;
    cout << "Enter model name: " << endl;
    cin >> Tech1.model;
    cout << "Enter Price: " << endl;
    cin >> Tech1.price;
    cout << "Enter screen size: " << endl;
    cin >> Tech1.screensize;
    cout << "Enter storage: " << endl;
    cin >> Tech1.storage;
}
void getFashionFeaturs() {
    cout << "Enter Product Code: " << endl;
    cin >> Fash1.productcode;
    cout << "Enter Brand name: " << endl;
    cin >> Fash1.brand;
    cout << "Enter model name: " << endl;
    cin >> Fash1.model;
    cout << "Enter Price: " << endl;
    cin >> Fash1.price;
    cout << "Enter size: " << endl;
    cin >> Fash1.size;
    cout << "Enter gender: " << endl;
    cin >> Fash1.gender;
}
```

these are the display functions same with the get info functions I used a dot between the struct name and the variable to try and get the info to print, I don't know if this part is working or not because I couldn't get the info in the variables in the first place.

```
void displayTechFeatures() {
    cout << "product code: " << Tech1.productcode << "\nBrand name: " << Tech1.brand << "\n model name: " << Tech1.model << "\nPrice: " << Tech1.price << "\n screen size: " << Tech1.screensize << "\storage: " << Tech1.storage << endl;

}

void displayFashionFeatures() {
    cout << "product code: " << Fash1.productcode << "\nBrand name: " << Fash1.brand << "\n model name: " << Fash1.model << "\nPrice: " << Fash1.price << "\n size: " << Fash1.size << "\ngender: " << Fash1.gender << endl;

}
```

the main function where I get the users choice of what he wants to do based on a switch statement and then call the functions in question.
I also tried calling the functions through a cout line like in case 5
but yeah it's not working.

```
int main() {
    
    int choice;
    cout << "1) add a new tech product.\n2)add a new Fashion product.\n3)display tech products info.\n4)display products of fashion info.\n5)display all products.\n6)Exit." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: getTechFeaturs; 
        break;

    case 2: getFashionFeaturs; 
        break;

    case 3: displayTechFeatures; break;

    case 4: displayFashionFeatures; break;

    case 5: cout << displayTechFeatures << "\n\n" << displayFashionFeatures; break;

    case 6: cout << "Thank you."; break;

    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Statements like `getTechFeaturs;` do not call functions. You're missing parenthesis: `getTechFeaturs();`

Comment: Post the correct code.

Comment: Please don't use global variables. Define objects locally, and pass as *arguments* to functions you call, if they need the objects.

Comment: fwiw this has nothing to do with structures. You can remove all `struct`s from the code and the issue will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the () to call your functions, simply for that reason it didn't do anything when it theoretically called each one of them, I leave here the main with the well written calls.

```
int main() {
    
    int choice;
    cout << "1) add a new tech product.\n2)add a new Fashion product.\n3)display tech products info.\n4)display products of fashion info.\n5)display all products.\n6)Exit." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: getTechFeaturs(); 
        break;

    case 2: getFashionFeaturs(); 
        break;

    case 3: displayTechFeatures(); break;

    case 4: displayFashionFeatures(); break;

    case 5: cout << displayTechFeatures() << "\n\n" << displayFashionFeatures(); break;

    case 6: cout << "Thank you."; break;

    }



    return 0;
}
```

The () should also be added to the other modules but that's up to you :D